# parent selector in less

Tags: css, less

Normally in less to reference a parent selector is:

```
.parent {
    .grand-pa & {
       /* this rules will apply to: .grand-pa .parent {....}
       background: grey;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something similar. example code HTML:

```
    <div class="panel panel-parent">
        <div class="panel-child">
            {{content}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Less code:

```
.panel {
    .panel-child {
        // some rules
        &.panel-parent & {  //<=== IS IT POSSIBILE SOMETHING LIKE THIS??
            // .panel.panel-parent .panel-child{...}
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution I have found is to repeat .panel-child:

```
.panel {
        &.panel-parent .panel-child {  //<=== Workaround
            // .panel.panel-parent .panel-child{...}
        }        
        .panel-child {
        // some rules
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of classes of the same element does not actually matter, i.e. `.panel.panel-parent` is equal to `.panel-parent.panel` (both will match  `<div class="panel panel-parent">`), thus you can get what you need with just:

```
.panel {
    .panel-child {
        a: a;
        .panel-parent& {
            b: b;
        }
    }
}
```

instead.

Comment: Very nice idea I'd say :)

Comment: Great. I knew about the order but not about the '&' property used like this. Thanks

Comment: Too tempting to mention examples [there](https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/40#issuecomment-29957430) then ;).