# Less parent :hover without another selector

Tags: css, less

I've read a lot of questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843806/parent-selector-in-less), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908818/less-parent-selector-for-first-parent), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186972/parent-selector-nested-inside-hover) etc.) here about this topic but I didn't find the exact case like mine.

So I want to set style to element but override it when parent in `:hover`.

Something like this:

**less**

```css
.gray-images > li > a {
  img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;

    selector { /* <-- That's what I'm looking for I want to override it when the user hover on the `a` element */
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    }
  }
}
```

**html**

```html
<ul class="gray-images">
  <li>
    <a href="#href">
      <img src="the_src" height="20"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In simple words: I want to set the `img` inside a `a`to `grayscale:1`. When the user `:hover` on the img's parent (the `a` tag) set the image to `grayscale:0`.

I know that there are a tricks like defined the parent's selector as variable and use it 2 times. But my question is if there is a "straight" way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer for Less nesting and Parent selector question:**

**No**, at present you can't nest the `:hover` selector of the `a` within the `img` block because currently whenever we use the `&` (parent selector) it always refers to the full parent from the topmost level.

The only choice would be to nest it within the `a` like in the below snippet.

```
.gray-images > li > a {
  img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
  }
  &:hover img { 
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  }  
}
```

---

**Alternate solution:** (the primary motive behind an extra answer on similar lines to those linked in Qn)

If the structure is exactly as you've mentioned in the question (that is, the `a` has only the `img` and no extra content) and no extra margins then you could do it like below (basically applying the filter to the `a` itself than the `img`).

```
.gray-images > li > a {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  &:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  }  
}
```

```css
.gray-images > li > a {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.gray-images > li > a:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<ul class="gray-images">
  <li>
    <a href="#href">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1" height="100">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using now, but I hoped that there is a better way, Thanks anyway..

Comment: @MoshFeu: I've added another option also and you may find it useful depending on your exact HTML structure. This (second snippet) is why I wanted to post a separate answer in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks again! Well, it's make sense. You are right, in the specific case, it can be done just on the `a` tag. BUT as you imagine that this question is generic and I have a lot of cases that I can't do this.

Comment: I do @MoshFeu. There is a feature request pending (as you'd have seen from the linked threads) which when implemented will open up a lot of good things for us :)